# Error when starting Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, emulation, tmp

I am new to Android Studio and fairly new to MacOSX and I have the following error when starting my app in an emulator

03/23 18:17:24: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/Dave/AndroidStudioProjects/Cookies/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.cookies
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory
Error while Installing APK

Do I need to create the /data/local/tmp/ folder?
If yes where do I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that Android Studio reinstall could solve the problem or try to delete your virtual device and create a new one.

Comment: Brill, it works I deleted all the virtual devices and added a new one, the smallest in the list. It still took 7 minutes to run though.

Comment: What is the config of your Mac?

Comment: I have a MacBook that I use for Android Studio and when I started out it was completely unusable taking 5 to 10 minutes for a build even for the smallest app. More memory added - I originally had 2GB and now have 8GB also using actual Android hardware.

My MacBook spec is as follows - macOS Sierra Version 10.12.3 MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010) Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Memory 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3 Graphics NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB 
The phone I use for build is an LG Sporty using Android 4.4.2 KitKat

Android Studio has the Intel HAXM extensions loaded and switched on.